# How many joins contemporary database systems are able to execute?

Tags: sql, database, join, inner-join

Let's consider some contemporary relational database. How many tables can we  join and get result in reasonable time? I know that it depends on things like hardware, presence of indices and size of table.  However, try to give me some intuition, please.

Moreover, I am aware of the fact that there are many type of joins like MergeJoins, HashJoin and so on.

Comment: there really is no way to answer this question since systems vary so much in capacity --- However most modern systems on reasonable hardware are able to handle 100+ in reasonable time.

Comment: It is a red flag you are asking this question -- I expect your data model is not good.

Comment: No, I am only intrested as CS student :)

Comment: They can handle more joins than you can reasonably write in a query.  The number of joins is not a limiting factor when writing queries.

Comment: 100 joins? really? Read: https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/02/06/neo4j-is-faster-than-mysql-in-performing-recursive-query/

Comment: even in case when we join tables with  100 000 000  rows?

Comment: What did you learn searching the manual for your DBMS version?

Comment: The key is in your phrase "and get result in reasonable time". You can easily join 100+ tables and views. Now, the cost (and execution time) will depend on how many rows you are reading on each table and which kind of combination of them are you using. If the right filters are in place a 100+ tables join can perform quite well. On the other hand, if you are performing a cross join between 1 million rows from one table against another 1 million rows from another table, it will be slow.

Comment: @nrz53378 - no sure the point of linking that article -- seems to back up what we are say